# Keytool isn't asking to set key password (keypass)

Tags: java, spring-security, keystore, keytool, jks

I tried creating a keytool using the following command in my C:\Program Files\Java\jdk15.x.x_x\bin.:

```
keytool -genkey -alias demospring -keyalg RSA -keystore demospring.jks -keysize 2048
```

I am being asked to create the password, but not the alias password. Am I missing something?
I am still pretty new to the concept.
Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: What version of Java are you using?

Comment: @always_a_rookie Java 15

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since Java version 9, it has transitioned the default `JKS` keystore to `PKCS12` ([read here](https://blogs.oracle.com/jtc/jdk9-keytool-transitions-default-keystore-to-pkcs12)). JKS is java's proprietary format and PKCS12 is more of a standard format (which is understood by various other applications).

The difference between these two formats in terms of the `keypass` is, in `JKS` you can set different keystore password (password that protects the keystore) and key password (a second password that protects the key, could be same as keystore), but for `pkcs12`, they both **have** to be the same.

Since the `storepass` and `keypass` are the same, `keytool` won't prompt the keypass, it will just use the storepass. Once you create your keystore, if you see the details of the keystore using `-list` command it will show you its format.

---

If you pass in the `keypass` argument for `PKCS12` keystore, keytool will show you this warning:

> Warning:  Different store and key passwords not supported for PKCS12 KeyStores. Ignoring user-specified -keypass value.

You can change the keystore type format with the `-storetype` argument, But if you use storetype as `JKS`, keytool will show you this warning:

> Warning: The JKS keystore uses a proprietary format. It is recommended to migrate to PKCS12 which is an industry standard format using "keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore demospring.jks -destkeystore demospring.jks -deststoretype pkcs12".